# How to get combine arrays key value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I try to get combine arrays value from an array.
here is my array:

```
["question", index: 0, input: "question1"]
```

In console:

```
Array[1]
   0: "question"
   index: 0
   input: "question1"
   length: 1
   __proto__: Array[0]
```

Here is my code:

```
var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
    var i = 0;
    keys.forEach(function () {
        var re = /question/i;
            var keysArr = keys[i].match(re);
            console.log(keysArr);
        i++;
    });
```

localStorage Set code:

```
var targetParam = window.location.search;
var questionIndex = targetParam.replace('?page_id=', '');
var i = 0;
var arr = [];
$("input[name='option[]']:checked").each(function () {
    arr[i++] = $(this).val();
});
localStorage[questionIndex] = arr;
```

I want to get the "question1" from the array. how can I get this?

Comment: `array.input` ?

Comment: i try this. console shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of null

Comment: Well you have to replace `array` with whatever the variable is that holds the array. You have not supplied this so I supplied a placeholder name.

Comment: How is `["question", index: 0, input: "question1"]` created?

Comment: localStorage has saved data and when match the reGex then keysArr veriable create that.

Comment: Change `console.log(keysArr)` to `console.log(keysArr.input)`

Comment: `["question", index: 0, input: "question1"]` logs a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Nothing happend. i already try this. console shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of null

Comment: Can you include how `localStorage` is set at Question?

Comment: @guest `console.log("question1".match(/question/i));`

Comment: @ikram `console.log("question1".match(/question/i).input);` returns "question1" for me

Comment: @TinyGiant Not certain what you are trying to communicate? How does OP get the array at Question?

Comment: @guest running that line in your console should return the array described in the question

Comment: @TinyGiant Ah, OP is trying to filter result from `.match()`. What is issue with using `localStorage.getItem("question")`?

Comment: i update my code: localStorage set code.

Comment: `localStorage` expects value to be a string, not array. `localStorage[questionIndex] = JSON.stringify(arr)`

Comment: automatically saved string. that not chellenge for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically saved string"? `.toString()` being called on `arr`? What is issue?

Comment: automatically saved like that    MySQL,PostgreSQL

Comment: Requirement is not clear. `localStorage["abc"] = [1,2,3]` returns `"1,2,3"` at call to `localStorage.getItem("abc")`.  `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` are not used at `javascript` at Question. `.forEach()` is not necessary where only one item is set at `localStorage`. What expected result?

Comment: @guest the array in question is not stored in localStorage but is generated by iterating the keys of `localStorage` itself and looking for keys containing "question". In the case of the array described in the question, the key would have been "question1" when logged.

Comment: @TinyGiant _"the array in question is not stored in localStorage"_ ? An array cannot be stored at `localStorage`, though OP tries at _"`localStorage[questionIndex] = arr;`"_ There is only one item stored at `localStorage` at `javascript` at Question, an array converted to a string by `.toString()`. `.forEach()` is not necessary to iterate a single string.

Comment: Well in that part the array is converted to a string using the built in `.toString` method presumably to be parsed in some way at a later point; which is entirely beside the point because the snippet that generates the array structure quoted at the beginning of the question has nothing to do with the array that is converted to a string there. The array that the op is asking about is generated from a regex match.

Comment: The OP is iterating `Object.keys(localStorage)` which is an array of property names from the localStorage object, not a string, nor the string representation of the array created in the last snippet.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, an array containing a single element which is a single string. "question" or "question1" will be in single string. Not clear, from perspective here, what expected result is.

Comment: @guest There is one key in localStorage: `question1`. The code iterates the result of `Object.keys(localStorage)` which is `["question1"]`. In this single iteration "question1" is matched against the regex `/question/i`. The returned regex match result array consists of the matched text ("question"), the current iteration index (0), and the input supplied to the regex ("question1"). The OP is asking how to retrieve the `input` property ("question1") from the regex match result array.

Comment: The whole complexity here is irrelevant to the question being asked because the [mcve] is `"question1".match(/question/i)` and the answer is `"question1".match(/question/i).input`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134853/discussion-on-question-by-ikram-hasib-how-to-get-combine-arrays-key-value-in-jqu).

Answer (score 0):

> here is my array:
>
> ```
> ["question", index: 0, input: "question1"]
> ```
>
> I want to get the "question1" from the array. how can I get this?

The important bit in the code is this

```
var re = /question/i;
var keysArr = keys[i].match(re);
console.log(keysArr);
```

This part of your loop matches the current value being iterated against a RegExp.

The following snippet—when run in a console—should generate the array described in your question

```js
console.log("question1".match(/question/i));
// ["question", index: 0, input: "question1"]
```

If you want to access the `input` property of the array object, you can use either dot notation or bracket notation:

```js
var keysArr = "question1".match(/question/i);
console.log(keysArr.input);    // "question1"
console.log(keysArr['input']); // "question1"
```

Though using bracket notation like this is not recommended because you know the property name, and there are no special characters that would require it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your matching data is not null. then you do someting..

```
var re = /question/i;
var keysArr = keys[i].match(re);
if (keysArr) { //checking keysArr is not null
    console.log(keysArr.input);
}
```

Result > "question1"

Comment: Yes. thanks .  i got this another way that you commented before. `var keysArr = keys[i].match(re).input`